# Sessions not being created by form?

Tags: php, session

I am trying to create a session for each field of a form so that I can call it back in on the additional information form on the next page.

```
<?php 
 session_start(); // starting the session

 if (isset($_POST['Submit'])) { 

     $_SESSION['breakdowndate'] = $_POST['breakdowndate'];
     $_SESSION['policyinception'] = $_POST['policyinception'];
     $_SESSION['customername'] = $_GET['customername'];
     $_SESSION['customersurname'] = $_GET['customersurname'];
     $_SESSION['covertype'] = $_POST['covertype'];
     $_SESSION['vehiclemake'] = $_POST['vehiclemake'];
     $_SESSION['vehiclemodel'] = $_POST['vehiclemodel'];
     $_SESSION['vehiclereg'] = $_POST['vehiclereg'];
     $_SESSION['vehicleage'] = $_POST['vehicleage'];
     $_SESSION['excess'] = $_POST['excess'];
     $_SESSION['mileage'] = $_POST['mileage'];
     $_SESSION['paid'] = $_POST['paid'];
     $_SESSION['HSRS'] = $_POST['HSRS'];
     $_SESSION['fault'] = $_POST['fault'];
     $_SESSION['garage'] = $_POST['garage'];
     $_SESSION['telephone'] = $_POST['telephone'];

    } 

?>
```

Using some code and after a few modifications I have the code above trying to store data that has been submitted in the form..

How can I improve this code to make it work?

Comment: do you store all POST data into session ?

Comment: The data is stored in a database after the form is completed, but the form has two stages. the intial stage captures all of the information that you can see in the example above. The user is then taken to a form that requires additional information to be added for the customer, I though this was the best way of doing it? I may be wrong though. If there is another way to add information to the just created client then I am open to suggestions.

Comment: is the next page the page you go to when submitting this form? if so, if the action of this form is to go to that page. I tought you should be able to access the post values on the next page. you can get it by just doing the following for example: `<input type="text" name="garage" value="<?= $_POST['garage'] ?>">` **Note your host needs to support `php short tags`** else just use `<?php echo ... ?>`

Comment: @SuperDJ — **Danger**: That code is [vulnerable to XSS](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-site_Scripting_(XSS)). User input needs escaping before being inserted into an HTML document!

Comment: @Quentin I know that but the OP should already do that. he might have left it out in the code

Comment: if i get right  what you trying to do, i guess you can just store user id in stage1 so you can fetch user data in stage2 with that id

Comment: @SuperDJ — No, the OP wasn't outputting any user input at all. The security vulnerability was introduced by your code.

Comment: @DGTLSS — What makes you think that code isn't working? (You haven't shown any code that tries to read the data back from the session).

Comment: @Quentin it was only an example. I don't say the OP should use it. And if he would use it he can still escape the user input after submitting the additional info

Comment: if I have 50 users all using this form at once and I use post values will that work? or will it cause a jumble of information?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it is not working, try debugging.

If it is saving the POST, then there is not much left to do.

Set `session.cookie.secure` to true. You may want to set `session.cookie_lifetime`.

As far as security, consider if you have something worth protecting. Does it matter if someone gets a visitor's session cookie?  If not, forget it.

```
session_set_cookie_params(0, '/', '', true, false);
session_start(); 

error_reporting(E_ALL);  // debug

if (isset($_POST['Submit'])) { 
  $_SESSION['breakdowndate'] = $_POST['breakdowndate'];
  $_SESSION['policyinception'] = $_POST['policyinception'];
  $_SESSION['customername'] = $_GET['customername'];
  $_SESSION['customersurname'] = $_GET['customersurname'];
  $_SESSION['covertype'] = $_POST['covertype'];
  $_SESSION['vehiclemake'] = $_POST['vehiclemake'];
  $_SESSION['vehiclemodel'] = $_POST['vehiclemodel'];
  $_SESSION['vehiclereg'] = $_POST['vehiclereg'];
  $_SESSION['vehicleage'] = $_POST['vehicleage'];
  $_SESSION['excess'] = $_POST['excess'];
  $_SESSION['mileage'] = $_POST['mileage'];
  $_SESSION['paid'] = $_POST['paid'];
  $_SESSION['HSRS'] = $_POST['HSRS'];
  $_SESSION['fault'] = $_POST['fault'];
  $_SESSION['garage'] = $_POST['garage'];
  $_SESSION['telephone'] = $_POST['telephone'];
} else {
  echo '<h3>Session Not Saved</h3>';
}

echo htmlentities(var_export($_REQUEST, true));  // debug
echo htmlentities(var_export($_SESSION, true));  // debug
```

---

**DEBUG**

It should work - if not, test and debug.

Show all Warnings.

Check `$_SESSION` after setting.

Check Request.

`$_REQUEST` includes `$_COOKIE` which should contain a SESSION cookie.

Answer (score 0):

We need to regenerate id. Try this. (Sorry for bad english)

```
<?php 
 session_start(); // starting the session

 if (isset($_POST['Submit'])) { 
     session_regenerate_id();
     $_SESSION['breakdowndate'] = $_POST['breakdowndate'];
     $_SESSION['policyinception'] = $_POST['policyinception'];
     $_SESSION['customername'] = $_GET['customername'];
     $_SESSION['customersurname'] = $_GET['customersurname'];
     $_SESSION['covertype'] = $_POST['covertype'];
     $_SESSION['vehiclemake'] = $_POST['vehiclemake'];
     $_SESSION['vehiclemodel'] = $_POST['vehiclemodel'];
     $_SESSION['vehiclereg'] = $_POST['vehiclereg'];
     $_SESSION['vehicleage'] = $_POST['vehicleage'];
     $_SESSION['excess'] = $_POST['excess'];
     $_SESSION['mileage'] = $_POST['mileage'];
     $_SESSION['paid'] = $_POST['paid'];
     $_SESSION['HSRS'] = $_POST['HSRS'];
     $_SESSION['fault'] = $_POST['fault'];
     $_SESSION['garage'] = $_POST['garage'];
     $_SESSION['telephone'] = $_POST['telephone'];
     session_write_close();
    } 

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Store your variables in an array and loop as shown below. You can use `session_start();` on your next page and access them:

```
<?php 
         session_start(); // starting the session
        $sessionItems = array('breakdowndate','policyinception','customername'...'telephone');

         if (isset($_POST['Submit'])) { 
             foreach($sessionItems as $item) {
               $_SESSION[$item] = $_POST[$item];
             }
          } 

        ?>
```

Comment: This appears to be a (subjectively) better way of writing the same code. How does it solve the problem the question is asking about though?